# How to avoid gimbal lock using device orientation to move camera position in ThreeJS?

Tags: matrix, three.js, linear-algebra, quaternions, gyroscope

I'm trying to use the browser's `deviceorientation` to move a camera in a ThreeJS scene, but am unable to avoid gimbal lock when beta hits 90.

I've created a demo site here: https://mattparrilla.github.io/gimbal-lock

Load the site on a mobile device and move the phone to portrait (so phone is upright along the gravity vector) and wiggle it around to see the cube move wildly.

Here is the meat of my code:

```
let initialOrientation;
function onDeviceOrientation (e) {
  // use initial angle as our "origin"
  if (!initialOrientation) {
    initialOrientation = {
      alpha: e.alpha,
      beta: e.beta,
      gamma: e.gamma
    }
  }
  
  // move camera X and Y positions between -5 and 5 depending on
  // angles of beta and gamma, keeping Z position fixed
  // the calc[Gamma|Beta]Offset functions maps my angle between -1 and 1 for use with lerp
  camera.position.set(
    THREE.MathUtils.lerp(0, 5, calcGammaOffset(e.gamma, initialOrientation.gamma)),
    THREE.MathUtils.lerp(0, 5, calcBetaOffset(e.beta, initialOrientation.beta)),
    5
  )
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I know I need to use either quaternions or rotation matrices, and I can calculate either (ThreeJS has convenient methods) I just don't understand them well enough to translate from existing examples to my own use case.

The entire app can be viewed here: https://github.com/mattparrilla/gimbal-lock

Comment: See `jsm/DeviceOrientationControls.js`, and an example of its use. It was removed from the three.js examples in [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/22654) PR.

Comment: Have you considered using A-Frame?  look-controls with "magicWindowTracking" set to true will do all this for you (and handle permissions as well) out of the box.
https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/look-controls.html#properties_magicwindowtrackingenabled